# Cassandra data files MUCH larger than expected

Tags: cassandra

I just did an experiment in which I loaded around a dozen csv files, weighing in at around 5.2 GB (compressed). After they are uploaded to Cassandra, they take up 64 GB! (actually around 128 GB but that is due to replication factor being 2).

Frankly I expected Cassandra's data to take up even less than the original 5.2 GB csv because:
1. Cassandra should be able to store data (mostly numbers) in binary format instead of ascii
2. Cassandra should have split a single file into its column constituents and improved compression dramatically

I'm completely new to Cassandra and this was an experiment. It is entirely possible that I misunderstand the product or mis-configured it.

Is it expected that 5.2 GB csvs will end up as 64 GB cassandra files?

EDIT: Additional info:

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.11 | CQL spec 3.2.1 | Native protocol v3]


[~]$ nodetool status
Datacenter: DC1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address      Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                                 Rack
UN  xx.x.xx.xx1  13.17 GB   256     ?       HOSTID  RAC1
UN  xx.x.xx.xx2  14.02 GB   256     ?       HOSTID  RAC1
UN  xx.x.xx.xx3  13.09 GB   256     ?       HOSTID  RAC1
UN  xx.x.xx.xx4  12.32 GB   256     ?       HOSTID  RAC1
UN  xx.x.xx.xx5  12.84 GB   256     ?       HOSTID  RAC1
UN  xx.x.xx.xx6  12.66 GB   256     ?       HOSTID  RAC1

du -h [director which contains sstables before they are loaded]: 67GB
```

Comment: What version? Big difference here between 2.2 and 3.0. Also is compression enabled? Whats your schema? ```nodetool tablestats``` output available?

Comment: Did the 64 GB bychance include the commit log?

Comment: @ChrisLohfink I added version info. `nodetool tablestats` doesn't seem to exist for me. After your comment I looked up table compression. Looks like I can alter my tables. Do you know of any references which discuss size vs write speed tradeoff?

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus I don't think commit logs are included in the size. I just checked the directory where I prepare sstables, before the are loaded. They are also around the same size.

Comment: 2.1 is old, use ```nodetool cfstats```. if you want less storage in 2.1 use ```COMPACT STORAGE``` option (you will never be able to modify schema though but significantly reduces size) and make sure you have compression enabled (which should be). It will still likely be larger then your inputted data, a ```nodetool compact``` may help to put it in single sstable.